# ListBox CollectiovViewSource.Filter changes selected item?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox that has items defined by a data template.
I also have a textbox where the user can type and I take the text and filter items in the listbox using the Filter property on the CollectionviewSource...as:

```
ICollectionView listBoxView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myListBox.ItemsSource);

            listBoxView.Filter = ((item) => { // Filtering logic };
```

This works great. However, this also clears out the SelectedItem of the ListBox, which I dont neccessarily want to. So before the user starts typing in the listbox, lets say that an item is already selected, the filtering logic seems to clear out the selection.
Is there a way to avoid that...? 
Thanks!

Comment: You could add `&& item.SelectedValue != listView.SelectedValue` or the equivalent to whatever your filtering logic is.

Comment: @keyboardP Thanks for your suggestion, howverv, if the selected item is "New York" and the user types "CAL" then I dont want to show the "New York". When the user backspaces and clears out the text, then the listbox shows all items and I want the "New York" to be still selected...This may not work with yur logic right?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, I thought you wanted to keep the selected item and display the filtered items. What you could do in that case is store the `SelectedIndex` somewhere after it's been selected. Then handle the TextBox's `OnTextChanged` event. In this event, check if the TextBox is empty. If it is, use `listView.SelectedIndex = storedSelectedIndex`.

Comment: @keyboardP Thanks. I thought of that. But then, we do a bunch of server side logic when the selected index changes and I dont want to re-do that by re-selecting the item. If there was a way to presever the selection, that would be great. I would have to use your suggestion if there is no other way i guess..

Comment: AFAICT there's no easy way of preserving the selection directly. You can prevent your server side logic from being recalled though. In the `OnTextChanged` event, simply detach the event handler for `SelectedIndexChanged` then reattach it. `listView.SelectedIndexChanged -= listView_SelectedIndexChanged; listView.SelectedIndex = storedSelectedIndex; listView.SelectedIndexChanged += listView_SelectedIndexChanged;` (I assume the server side stuff is called within the `SelectedIndexChanged` event). Not the nicest piece of code but I think it may work here.

Comment: @keyboardP . That is interesting, So the selection change wont be fired in this case? I would have to just reqire it ... which will prevent my logic from running...

Comment: Yes, if you detach the handler, the selection change handler won't be called (even though the ListView itself will function as normal and will register the selection changed). You can then set the index without it calling your handler code before reattaching it and having everything work as before :) The alternative to messing with the event handler is to have a `bool` flag which you can set. If it's true, execute server code, other don't.

Comment: @keyboardP There is no SelectedIndexChanged event on ListBox in wpf?

Comment: No, you want to detach the handler from the `ListView` because I assume that's where your server side code is being fired from. User selects item from ListView --> SelectedIndexChanged event fired --> Your server code is called (please correct me if I'm wrong about that). So you want to detach the handler there to ensure your server side code is not called when you're manually resetting the index.

Comment: I know that but I have a ListBox not a ListView ... maybe I should have edited my question to not have listView as local variable.

Comment: lol! I thought you had a ListView which was being filtered :D In that case, it's the same principle but with the `SelectionChanged` event :)

Comment: :) Thank you. Let me try that.